# nonlinear pde equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

I want to solve the problem: find some non-trivial particular solution of nonlinear PDE. Are the any methods for this? I understand that there is no general method to find general solution, but..
One of the equation is
$$u_{t}+u^2 u_{x}-u_{xxx}=0$$

Comment: Not $u_{tt} -u_{xx} = 2u^3 -u$ anymore? I am writing an answer using perturbation method for that.

Answer (score 4):

$$u_{t}+u^2 u_y-u_{yyy}=0$$
This PDE may be rewritten as a (modified) [Korteweg–de Vries Equation](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/npde/npde5103.pdf) after the substitutions $\displaystyle u(t,y)=\sqrt{6}\,i\,w(t,x)\;$ and $\;y=-x\,$ that give :
$$w_t+w_{xxx}+6w^2w_x=0$$
with different kinds of solutions provided in the EqWorld link.

[Polyanin's EqWorld](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/index.htm) that should be recommended for any difficult ODE or PDE !

Answer (score 3):

You can always look for travelling wave solutions. Setting $u(x,t)=v(x-ct)$ (where $c$ is an arbitrary constant parameter) we find that $v(\xi)$ satisfies an *ordinary* differential equation:
$$v'''=(v^2-c)v'.\tag{1}$$
This can be integrated in quadratures:

- First, we obviously have
  $$v''=\frac13v^3-cv+A\tag{2}$$
- Multiplying (2) by $2v'$, we integrate once more:
  $$ (v')^2=\frac{1}{6}v^4-cv^2+2Av+B\tag{3}$$
- Finally, (3) is separable:
  $$\int\frac{dv}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{6}v^4-cv^2+2Av+B}}=\pm\xi+C.\tag{4}$$

Here $A$, $B$, $C$ are three arbitrary constants of integration. The integral on the left can be computed explicitly in terms of elliptic functions. It simplifies to trigonometric functions if we set $A=B=0$: this is the so-called *one-soliton solution* of mKdV. For non-zero $A$, $B$ (4) is the simplest example of *finite-gap* solutions.

Maybe it is worth mentioning that such travelling wave solutions will exist for (more or less) any evolutionary PDE which does not contain $x$, $t$ explicitly. Now as pointed by **Raymond Manzoni**, your PDE is special: it is an *integrable* equation which has many special features like infinite number of conserved quantities, an associated linear problem, etc. In particular, this manifests itself in the possibility of constructing *multi-soliton* solutions.

In case you would like to learn more about integrable stuff, I strongly recommend the book [*Solitons: Differential equations, symmetries, and infinite-dimensional algebras*](http://books.google.fr/books?id=kQDw1ZcqLjUC&printsec=frontcover&hl=uk&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0) by M. Jimbo, T. Miwa and E. Date. With a minimal effort, it can be found online.